# Tkinter/ttk frame size

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to set the frame size via theme_settings and it just doesn't work.

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

root = Tk()

style = Style()
style.theme_settings('default',{'TFrame':{'configure':{'width':100, 'height':100}}})

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But if I set it explicitly, then it works:

```
frame.configure(width=100, height=100)
```

Why?

ttk.**version** = "0.3.1"

Tkinter.**version** = "$Revision: 81008 $"

P.S. I need to set this size via .theme_settings() method, the question exactly about it.

UPD: I've checked the same behavior with Button element and it works. Something is wrong with frames...

```
style = Style()
style.theme_settings('default',{'TButton':{'configure':{'width':100}}})

button = Button(root)
button.pack()
```

UPD2: The same story with 'padding'. It works with buttons, but not with frames. While frames 'background' for example can be set via theme_settings

Comment: btw: when I see `import *` I'm not sure weather you use `Tkinter.Frame` or `ttk.Frame`

Comment: I use ttk.Frame, the order matters

Comment: yes, order matter but don't like `import *` (as most programmers)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html - see 24.2.1. Using Ttk

Comment: well, you can replace Frame with ttk.Frame, it'll not change anything

Comment: read [PEP 0008 -- Style Guide for Python Code - Imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) - there is suggestion "do not use `import *`"

Comment: it is only comment - not answer.

Comment: Are you certain that your code uses the `'default'` theme? What does `style.theme_use()` return?

Comment: In all my years of coding I've never ever seen a program that tried to set a default size for a frame. Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this?

Comment: yes, it uses the default theme, but even if I set style.theme_use('default') it doesn't help anyway

Comment: I just use a simple case here. I have a program that gets such config (style) at start and builds custom GUI based on provided settings

Answer (score 1):

The Answer should be like that:

root = tk.Tk()

## width x height + x_offset + y_offset

root.geometry("500x300+250+100")

Answer (score 0):

Use the Place management as following codes:

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x300+250+100")    # width x height + x_offset + y_offset